# MongoDB Filter with Interval

Tags: mongodb

I have a database query that selects all documents having a timestamp field (tmp) falling in a certain range, like so

```
{ tmp: { '$gte': 1411929000000, '$lte': 1419010200000 } }
```

This query returns a large number of records, say 10000.

Objective: 
To fetch documents in the **same interval range**, *but separated by say (1 hour timestamp) interval in between* hence reduce the number of records that is fetched.

Is there a way of doing this entirely using MongoDB query system?

Any comments would be very helpful. Thanks.

EDITED:

Please see the comment below for more info:

[MongoDB Filter with Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565544/mongodb-filter-with-interval?noredirect=1#comment43580326_27565544)

Comment: You will have to traverse the cursor youve got. Its not directly possible via mongo. Or just calculate the hourly value and hit mongo with each hour segment

Comment: What are you doing with these records that makes it ok just to get a somewhat arbitrary subset of matching documents? That might help us cook up another solution besides breaking the query down into multiple queries for periods separated by an hour.

Comment: @shadab.tughlaq That's what I want to avoid... I do have it as a last resort but if I can get something better, then I will use that

Comment: @wdberkeley well due to NDA I can not show the code, but it basically contains Stock Exchange data (say in 1 minute interval). And the objective is to send a sample of these data between two endpoints (time) 

But the thing is, the client can ask for a 5 minute interval data or 10 min, or 1 hour etc, so from these 1 minute interval data I need to sample and send only the relevant ones. Hope that makes it more clear.